# How to direct the spool output from one server to another

Tags: plsqldeveloper

Hi I have a PL/SQL script which write its Spool output to a text file  and spool path is not specified so the file is getting generated within the folder where i keep the .bat script and Pl/SQL , My need is , is there any way to write the spool out from one server( remote machine) to MVS( mainframe system) without doing FTP?

I know we can specify the path within the server like SPOOL N:\folder\filename.txt but i want to specify it to different server (mainframe).

Comment: If the mainframe is available as a network share somehow, you could just do `myscript.bat > \\my\mainframe\folder\filename.txt` i suppose. If you can't mount the mainframe drive on your machine in any way I think you'll have to transfer the file via ftp/ssh/etc. after the script has created it on your disk.

Comment: thanks Joe i will try this , currently i am using FTP to transfer the files :-)